# How can I make the ImageView as the same size fitting to the image in in

Tags: imageview, titanium

I have picture s such as 33*120 (height*width)

it is transparent ping,so this size is including transparent area.

My code is like this

in xml

```
<ImageView id="Pic"/>
```

in tss

```
"#Pic": {
  backgroundColor:'blue',
  image:"./img/menuj.png"
  textAlign:Ti.UI.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_LEFT,
  height:'10%',
  left:'1%',
},
```

I would like to adjust imageview size to 10% height and width should keep the same ratio as original image size.

But,blue area(view) is much wider than I expected.
(blue area appears much bigger than image itself,moreover image file is not even left aligned in the view.)

How can I fit the ImageView to the image size?

Answer (score 0):

just pass to the imageview the height and width of the original image (in your case, since you want a different height, the image might get stretched/shrinked).

Like this:

```
"#Pic": {
 backgroundColor:'blue',
 image:"./img/menuj.png"
 textAlign:Ti.UI.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_LEFT,
 height:'10%',
 width: "120px"//PUT HERE THE WIDTH OF THE ORIGINAL IMAGE
 left:'1%',
 }
```

One last thing, drop the comma at the end of the tss description, it's not required.